# How to read one column from SQLite and store in Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have SQLite database with 5 columns named: `Name`, `ID`, `ChildID`, `ParentID`, `BrotherID`.

In this database I have many records and I want to store one of all columns value in array and return this array. For example I want to get all value in `ParentID` column. I use this query code:

`Select ParentID from Table1` (Table1 is name of table)

This is my code for get array from certain column :

```
/*==================================================================
 METHOD FOR GETTING MIDIFIED FROM DATABASE
 ==================================================================*/
- (NSMutableArray*)readingModified
{
     ModiArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    // Setup the database object
    sqlite3 *database2;
    // Open the database from the users filessytem
    if(sqlite3_open([[self DatabaseSqlite] UTF8String], &database2) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
        //SQLIte Statement
        NSString *sqlStatement_userInfo =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select ParentID from Table1"];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database2, [sqlStatement_userInfo UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                // Init the Data Dictionary
                NSMutableDictionary *_dataDictionary2=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                NSString *_recordParentID = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
                [_dataDictionary2 setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_recordModified] forKey:@"ParentID"];
                [array addObject:_dataDictionary2];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"No Data Found");
        }
        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database2);

    return ModiArray;
}
```

please tell me my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

my friend a few be careful.

this code is right but in line you mistake :
**[array addObject:_dataDictionary2];**

instead `array` put `ModiArray`

```
/*==================================================================
 METHOD FOR GETTING MIDIFIED FROM DATABASE
 ==================================================================*/
- (NSMutableArray*)readingModified
{
     ModiArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    // Setup the database object
    sqlite3 *database2;
    // Open the database from the users filessytem
    if(sqlite3_open([[self DatabaseSqlite] UTF8String], &database2) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
        //SQLIte Statement
        NSString *sqlStatement_userInfo =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select ParentID from Table1"];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database2, [sqlStatement_userInfo UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                // Init the Data Dictionary
                NSMutableDictionary *_dataDictionary2=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                NSString *_recordParentID = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
                [_dataDictionary2 setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_recordModified] forKey:@"ParentID"];
                [ModiArray addObject:_dataDictionary2];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"No Data Found");
        }
        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database2);

    return ModiArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are adding object to `array` and allocating and returning `ModiArray`.